How do I use MobileNetV2 model to use gray scale images
I am using the MobileNetV2 model as my base model, but I added 5 new trainable layers and I'm re-training it on two new categories: monkeypox positive and monkeypox negative. The monkeypox negative image folder includes different skin infections that look similar to monkeypox but are infections like chickenpox. I have a dataset with colored images, but I converted those to gray scale(code below).
When I tried to run the model, I got the issue of
Input 0 of layer "Conv1" is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to 
have value 3, but received input with shape (None, 200, 200, 1)

I know I have to trick the model into thinking the value of 1 is 3, but I'm not sure how. I am using imagenet for the weights.
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image as IMAGE
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os
os.environ["CUDA DEVICE ORDER"]="PCI BUS ID"
os.environ["CUDA VISIBLE DEVICES"]="0"

from tensorflow.keras import Model
from tensorflow.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2 import MobileNetV2, preprocess_input
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, GlobalAveragePooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import tensorflow as tf
from PIL import Image
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow

!pip3 install tensorflowjs

import tensorflowjs as tfjs

train = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1/255)
test = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1/255)
val = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1/255)

training_set = train.flow_from_directory("/content/drive/MyDrive/mpox_data/Train",
                                         target_size=(200,200),
                                         batch_size = 15,
                                         class_mode = "categorical",
                                         color_mode='rgb'
                                        )

testing_set = test.flow_from_directory("/content/drive/MyDrive/mpox_data/Test",
                                          target_size=(200,200),
                                          batch_size = 15,
                                          class_mode = "categorical",
                                       color_mode='rgb'
                                        )
validation_set = val.flow_from_directory("/content/drive/MyDrive/mpox_data/Val",
                                         target_size=(200,200),
                                         batch_size=15,
                                         class_mode = "categorical",
                                         color_mode='rgb'
                                         )

x, y = training_set[0]
a, b = testing_set[0]
d, c = validation_set[0]

base_model = MobileNetV2(weights = "imagenet", include_top = False)

x = base_model.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = Dense(42, activation="relu")(x)
x = Dense(64, activation = "relu")(x)
x = Dense(32, activation="relu")(x)
preds = Dense(2, activation = "sigmoid")(x)

model = Model(inputs = base_model.input, outputs = preds)

epochs = 5
optimizer = Adam(learning_rate = 0.0003)
model.compile(loss = "binary_crossentropy", optimizer = optimizer, metrics = ["Accuracy"])
model.fit(training_set, validation_data = validation_set, epochs = epochs, shuffle=True)

I tried to use grayscale images with the model, expecting to have it run successfully, but it gave me the error mentioned above.
Why does my program fail to work and how do I fix it, allowing the model to continue training itself on the grayscale images?

Your input needs three channels. That is, the image has to be in RGB/BGR format, no matter if the actual content is grayscale. Grayscale content is one-channel only, so you need to replicate the grayscale channel two extra times, and use that image array as input to the network.
There's more than a way to achieve this, I prefer to use OpenCV for this operation, but keep in mind this conversion won't be part of the tensorflow graph, since it uses an external library and runs on the CPU. It could be inside a generator function, though. The conversion would be something like this, assuming your input is a BGR image:
# To Grayscale (1-channel):
inputImage = cv2.cvtColor(inputImage, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) 
# Back to BGR (3-channels):
inputImage  = cv2.cvtColor(inputImage , cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

What follows is the usual scaling to [0.0, 1.0] with rescale.
Another option, using the tf.image functions to convert to grayscale then back to RGB. The preprocessing function can be then, called from an ImageDataGenerator:
def convertGrayscale(image):
    image = tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale(image)
    image = tf.image.grayscale_to_rgb(image)
    return image

tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1/255,
    preprocessing_function=convertGrayscale
)

Be aware, however, that ImageDataGenerator is now deprecated.
